# Export weka results on command line

Tags: command-line, machine-learning, weka

Is it possible to export weka results after execute it via command line?

What I am doing:

```
java -cp "./weka.jar" weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t "iris.arff" -i
```

But then, I have all the statistics in console, is there any way to export this? Or I have to read and write by myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example from the [Weka Primer](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer#Examples):

```
java -Xmx1024m weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t data.arff -i -k -d J48-data.model >&! J48-data.out &
```

So no, WEKA doesn't have a specific output parameter on the command line, but you simply redirect the output and errors to a file using `>&!` or only the output without errors using `>`.

In your case you could use this command to save the output to the file `NaiveBayes-iris.out`:

```
java -cp "./weka.jar" weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t "iris.arff" -i > NaiveBayes-iris.out
```

Comment: Thanks Sicco! Now im trying like you explained, like this: java -cp "./weka.jar" weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t "iris.arff" -i -k -d NaiveBayes-data.model >&! NaiveBayes-data.out ...but it returns: & was unexpected at this time. Do you know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Riba I updated my answer. You are using Windows right? The original answer was for Linux, but the added command in my answer should work.