# Run multiple classifiers on arff files in weka automatically

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, arff

I have to run many arff files in weka, and for each of them I have to run multiple classifiers- MLP, RandomForest,FURIA, etc., with different test options for each, and store each of their results. It is very time consuming to do each of them manually. I am looking for some method, or some script that can automate the process.
 I must confess that I am new to machine learning, and have no knowledge of scripting.  I found this- https://sites.google.com/site/svaisipour/utilities/cs-for-biologist/weka-runner , and though I get how to manipulate the classifiers here, I cant understand how to change the test options from cross-validation to percentage-split.

Please let me know of any method that might help me with this. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Weka Experimenter GUI for this.

[image]

A  big dialog box will appear next.

To get run experiments with multiple algorithms, you must click on the "New" Button there, and then... oh well, ... this [video about the experimenter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3eQpC8n8yA) will get  you started.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident to run Weka from your own Java code you can create an array of your chosen classifiers and files and loop through them doing your tests. The code would be something like this (for an 80/20 split between training and testing):

```
    String[] filePaths = {"/some/data1.arff", "/some/data2.arff", "/some/data3.arff"};
    for (String path : filePaths) {
        DataSource source = new DataSource(path);
        Instances data = source.getDataSet();
        if (data.classIndex() == -1) {
            data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
        }

        data.randomize(new java.util.Random(0));
        int trainSize = (int) Math.round(data.numInstances() * 0.8);
        int testSize = data.numInstances() - trainSize;
        Instances train = new Instances(data, 0, trainSize);
        Instances test = new Instances(data, trainSize, testSize);

        Classifier[] classifiers = {new NaiveBayes, new J48, new MultilayerPerceptron};

        for (Classifier c : classifiers) {
            Classifier cls = c;
            cls.buildClassifier(train);
            Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
            eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);
            System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run Weka from you command line. You will first need to add Weka.jar to you classpath. Then you can start reading files, running filters, classifiers, etc. through the command line. You can easily get started from [Weka Primer](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer).

As an example, you can run randomForest using the following command:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -I 10 -S 1 -t data.arff -x 10
```

Where:

```
-I <number of trees> Specifies the number of trees to build.
-S <seed number>  Specifies the seed for random number generator.
-t <name of training file> Sets training file.
-x <number of folds> Sets number of folds for cross-validation
```

You can find the detailed specification [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html).

If you want to use split-percentage rather than cross-validation, you simply replace

```
-x <number of folds>
```

with

```
-split-percentage <percentage>
```

Alternatively, you can specify a separate test set by -T:

```
-T <name of test file> Sets test file.
```

If you run the commands as stated, the results will be printed in the command line. If you want to save them in a separate file you can follow what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968966/export-weka-results-on-command-lin)